# we got errors using g++ in batch mode

Tags: c++, mingw-w64

compiling

```
#include <stdio.h> 
main()
{   int rtn=0;
    printf("\nmain hello world",rtn);
    fin:
    return(rtn);
}
```

interactive after installing DEV-CPP 
download from https://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/ 
with the embedded IDE
yields "successful installed"; 
trying the "same" with WINDOWS 7 pro 64bit OS batch script

```
set p1=-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\include"
set p2=-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include"
set p3=-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include"
set p4=-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++"
set p5=-L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib"
set p6=-L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib"
g++ -g cc_hello_world.cpp -o cc_hello_world -lm %p1% %p2% %p3% %p4% %p5% %p6%
```

yields endless error report beginning with

```
In file included from C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Dev-Cpp\\MinGW64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include\\_cygwin.h:14,
             from C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Dev-Cpp\\MinGW64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include\\_mingw.h:17,
             from C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Dev-Cpp\\MinGW64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include\\crtdefs.h:10,
             from C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Dev-Cpp\\MinGW64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include\\stdio.h:9,
             from cc_hello_world.cpp:1:
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Dev-Cpp\\MinGW64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include\\stddef.h:18:
 syntax error before `extern'
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Dev-Cpp\\MinGW64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include\\stddef.h:20:
 warning: ANSI C++ forbids declaration `errno_t' with no type
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Dev-Cpp\\MinGW64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include\\stddef.h:20:
 warning: `__cdecl__' attribute directive ignored
...
```

we cite only the first seven lines.
Though Albatross http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/36vU7k9E/ argued  we'd appreciate
some hint where to continue our studies to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: You should not need to list the standard include and library paths on the command line; the compiler normally considers them implicitly and in the correct order. This may actually be the problem.

Comment: this was the problem -- thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with your code, whether it's Batch or C++. If you're trying to print something to console and for some reason want to use a Batch script, use the `system()` command (I'd recommend abstracting it away in a recursive variadic function).

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <fstream>

void make_batch() { return; }
template<typename ComTy, typename... OtherTy>
void make_batch(std::ofstream& bat_file, ComTy command, OtherTy... other_commands)
{
    bat_file << command;
    make_batch(bat_file, std::forward<OtherTy>(other_commands)...);
}

template <typename... ComTy>
void batch(ComTy... commands)
{
    std::ofstream bat_file_write("temp.bat");
    if (bat_file_write.is_open())
    {
        // Make the batch script
        make_batch(bat_file_write, std::forward<OtherTy>(commands)...);
        bat_file_write.close();

        system("temp.bat");  // Execute the batch script
    }
}

int main()
{
    batch(
        "rtn=0",
        "echo.",
        "echo main hello world %rtn%",
        "fin:",
        "exit"
    );
}
```

However, if you mean that you just want to invoke the compiler from the command prompt, then you'll have to write the correct C++ code.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    int rtn = 0;
    printf("\nmain hello world %i", rtn);
    return rtn;
}
```

Then just compile that code like normal.

Now it's possible I'm not fully understanding your question. If that's the case, please let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: so we forgot the format directive %i; the devcpp compiler produced a running exe either (extra surprise) without error message pointing to this fault; next line in our batch script is HELLO_WORLD.EXE [argv] evtl called with actual parameters; bound to be brief we confined to the mere occurrence of the mentioned messages we suppose coming from devcpp IDE;

Comment: jacob solved our problem; this request may be closed